# How to use API.statuses_lookup in Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am looking an example how to use "API.statuses_lookup".

Answer (score 2):

use

```
tweets = self.api.statuses_lookup(tweetIDs)
```

tweetIDs is a list of your tweet ids ,which u have from ur database or somewhere else
in response you will get a status object
now use for loop

```
**for tweet in tweets:
   #tweet obtained
   print(str(tweet['id'])+str(tweet['text']))**
```

u can provide maximum 100 tweets