# get protected User Id from Tweet ID

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I am using [Tweepy](http://www.tweepy.org/) python library to implement twitter API. As for authorization, I am using tweepy.OAuthHandler. I have created a twitter app before that.

I have a bunch of tweet IDs (from a public dataset) of some twitter posts without original users.  I want to get the user screen_name/ UserID back using tweetID. Here is my psuedo code:

```
import tweepy
import json
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('consumer_key', 'consumer_secret')
auth.set_access_token('access_token', 'access_token_secret')
api = tweepy.API(auth)
jsonarray = api.statuses_lookup([tweetID1,tweetID2, ..., tweetIDn])
```

What I have seen that If I pass n tweetIDs, sometimes I get less than n elements in jsonarray. I suspect that it's because of the protected users who posted tweets. Is there any way to get user id/ screen name of the protected user?

Comment: Maybe try it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40405998/1248974

Answer (score 0):

I believe your assumption is correct. From the Twitter [GET statuses/lookup API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/lookup):

> You must be following a protected user to be able to see their most
>   recent Tweets. If you don’t follow a protected user their status will
>   be removed.